# Exibir valor json em uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Como fazer para um valor que esta no JS aparecer no conteúdo html?

**app.js**

```
 // BUSCA OCORRENCIAS
 $("#menuOcorrencia").click(function() {
     var operacao = "selectOcorrencias";
     $.getJSON("http://url.com.br/appOperacoes.php", {operacao:operacao,condominioID:condominioID}, function(selectOcorrencias){
        for (var seOcor in selectOcorrencias){
          document.write(selectOcorrencias[seOcor].ID_Ocorrencia + selectOcorrencias[seOcor].morador + "<br />");
        }
    });
});
```

parte do html que esta no index.html

```
<div class="list-group widget uib_w_44 d-margins" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_group" data-ver="1">
    <a class="list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_45" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/list_item" data-ver="1" id="btnOcorrenciaVer">
         <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading</h4>
         <p class="list-group-item-text">List item</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

O **FOR** deve acontecer listando o resultado que trouce do BD.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em **Heading** ficaria o `selectOcorrencias[seOcor].ID_Ocorrencia` e em **List item** ficaria `selectOcorrencias[seOcor].morador`

Essa DIV é única, é como se agrupasse todas as lista. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Joga o "html" dentro do loop for e vai dando append para exibir onde quer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que queres continuar a adicionar conteúdo vindo do JSON aqui: `<div class="list-group widget uib_w_44 d-margins"...`.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.list-group');
json.forEach(function(ocorrencia) {
    // link externo / wrapper
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.className = 'list-group-item allow-badge widget uib_w_45';
    a.setAttribute('data-uib', 'twitter%20bootstrap/list_item');
    a.setAttribute('data-ver', '1');
    a.id = ocorrencia.ID_Ocorrencia;
    // titulo
    var heading = document.createElement('h4');
    heading.className = 'list-group-item-heading';
    heading.innerHTML = 'Ocorrência: ' + ocorrencia.ID_Ocorrencia;
    // texto
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.className = 'list-group-item-text';
    p.innerHTML = ocorrencia.morador;

    // inserir no DOM
    a.appendChild(heading);
    a.appendChild(p);
    target.appendChild(a);
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/w8m7981d/

#### Nota:

No teu HTML tens IDs duplicadas. Isso é HTML inválido. IDs têm de ser únicas. Mudei isso na minha resposta, onde as IDs têm o mesmo numero que `ID_Ocorrencia`