# Programação em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como posso criar uma função em *JavaScript* que vai ter um parâmetro que vai receber o que o usuário digitar na tela e quer como retorno um *alert* com o que foi digitado pelo usuário?

Minha dúvida é como fazer com que a função pegue tal texto inserido.

Comment: Utilize o `let oQueFoiDigitado = window.prompt("Text");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por passos:

`a)` para receber input do utilizador e colocar numa variável:

```
const nome = prompt('Escreva um nome!');
```

`b)` mostrar o texto que foi inserido:

```
alert(nome);
```

Tudo junto numa função seria:

```js
function pedirNome() {
  const nome = prompt('Escreva um nome!');
  alert(`O nome inserido foi:\n\n${nome}`);
  return nome;
}

const nomeUtilizador = pedirNome();

// e aqui podes continuar a usar o que o utilizador inseriu
// dentro da variável "nomeUtilizador"
```

Comment: podedia me explicar mais ou menos como poderia reproduzir essa caixa de mensagem com um _div_ ?

Comment: @Gabriel podes ser mais claro? queres que em vez de um alert o texto apareça numa div? essa div já existe ou vais criar? Tenta ser o mais descritivo possível para percebermos o teu problema/dúvida.

Comment: Sim ao invés de um alert uma div. Vai ter a função que vai retornar a mensagem que o usuário digitou, e a div devera retornar o mesmo. Minha dúvida está na parte que da função retornar na div.

Comment: @Gabriel dá uma olhada aqui por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104926/129