# Como mostrar valor digitado em alert()?

Tags: javascript

Como mostrar o valor de um variável *string* ou digitado em um *prompt*?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function funcao()
    {
        var x;
        var quantidade = prompt("Digite valor do saque");
        x = quantidade;
        alert("$quantidade$");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Programação em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290827/programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-javascript)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

É só imprimir a variável, sem mais nada, você só usa aspas para colocar um texto, se quer que um símbolo do código seja resolvido e usado o seu valor então ele deve constar direto. Até existe como colocar uma variável dentro das aspas mas isso é mais avançado e não funciona em todas versões, então é melhor não usar por enquanto.

```js
function funcao() {
    var quantidade = prompt("Digite valor do saque");
    alert(quantidade);
}
funcao();
```

Se quiser imprimir um texto e a variável pode fazer uma concatenação simples:

```js
function funcao() {
    var quantidade = prompt("Digite valor do saque");
    alert("O valor digitado é " + quantidade);
}
funcao();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Alert.js).

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma:

```
"$quantidade$"
```

Você vai mostrar a string `$quantidade$`, para mostrar o valor da variável "quantidade", basta colocar o "quantidade" no alert, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
function funcao()
{
  var x;
  var quantidade = prompt("Digite valor do saque");
  x = quantidade;
  alert(quantidade);
}
funcao();
```